# jq variable substituion works in shell but not in script

Tags: bash, variables, jq, expansion

The following command works in the shell just fine, but when executed via an script it doesn't. What am I missing.

```
jsonSelectWords='select(.words!=6) | select(.words!=1173) | select(.words!=1) | select(.words!=8) | select(.words!=9) | select(.words!=27)'

cat file.json | jq "$jsonSelectWords"
```

In the script the select statement is created dynamically, thus I am not able to directly provide it.

```
input=file.json

local jsonSelectWords="'"
for word in "${wordDupArray[@]}"
do
    jsonSelectWords+="select(.words!=$word) | "
done
jsonSelectWords="${jsonSelectWords::-3}"
jsonSelectWords+="'"


cat $input | jq "$jsonSelectWords"
```

The execution of the last line gives the following error.

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:

'select(.words!=6) | select(.words!=1173) | select(.words!=1) | select(.words!=8) | select(.words!=9) | select(.words!=27)'

jq: 1 compile error
```

Any hints. It tried different variations as well as the whole statement in `$(cat $input | jq "$jsonSelectWords")`

I have also used the following
`cat $input | jq --args JSW "$jsonSelectWords" '$JSW'` (with single quotes removed from the initial string, with `'[$JSW]'` and so on). This just outputs the content of jsonSelectWords.

The following lines are examples of the content of `file.json` aka `$input`.

```
{"timestamp":"2022-03-09T12:30:23.329630917+01:00","scheme":"http","port":"80","path":"/","body-sha256":"0bfc0bdeb920ce4701f130e6e6a33c8aaf558fae44c7479cc1629930cb0f4535","header-sha256":"d9522b92bb09e71b719804f522f0b3b49aa77974c8d79e644fb45a7b3327f73e","a":["81.91.86.14"],"url":"http://01.akce.omv.com:80","input":"01.akce.omv.com","location":"https://01.akce.omv.com/","webserver":"openresty","content-type":"text/html","method":"GET","host":"81.91.86.14","content-length":95,"status-code":301,"response-time":"194.004475ms","failed":false,"lines":3,"words":6}
{"timestamp":"2022-03-09T12:30:23.355007661+01:00","scheme":"http","port":"80","path":"/","body-sha256":"d6285599bd6f2851fc17e0244ad212a58d8d539231f804f81b5b98289197afa0","header-sha256":"96884ec058c78d0ea282a2d51be4ce0f5c7bc05d8fe3e8dd8f6fb73dd4fa2cd6","a":["81.91.86.14","40.90.4.7","64.4.48.7","2603:1061::7","2620:1ec:8ec::7"],"url":"http://09-mail2.akce.omv.com:80","input":"09-mail2.akce.omv.com","location":"https://09-mail2.akce.omv.com/","webserver":"openresty","content-type":"text/html","method":"GET","host":"81.91.86.14","content-length":101,"status-code":301,"response-time":"233.377898ms","failed":false,"lines":3,"words":6}
{"timestamp":"2022-03-09T12:30:23.450849812+01:00","scheme":"http","port":"80","path":"/","body-sha256":"c186820e328bf631a2943f77e52e9e8319ddfefade6d308a2a22ef996176bbe6","header-sha256":"61e4f3139518b49cac86b77a4f9f06da98d53f2eb12dbff574b5a0ea66327478","a":["81.91.86.14"],"url":"http://09-server2.akce.omv.com:80","input":"09-server2.akce.omv.com","location":"https://09-server2.akce.omv.com/","webserver":"openresty","content-type":"text/html","method":"GET","host":"81.91.86.14","content-length":103,"status-code":301,"response-time":"268.856986ms","failed":false,"lines":3,"words":6}
```

### Solution

```
local jsonSelectWords=""
for word in "${wordDupArray[@]}"
do
    jsonSelectWords+="select(.words!=$word) | "
done
jsonSelectWords="${jsonSelectWords::-3}"

cat $input | jq "$jsonSelectWords"
```

Comment: Sorry, I have incorrectly transferred the script. It uses double qoutes in this case (it just doesn't use double quotes where I need them inside     `jsonSelectHost+='select(.host!="'"$host"'") | '`

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the JSON? I don't understand how your `jq` expression can work on it unless it is a simple singleton `{"words": "something"}`

Comment: It looks like you're including literal single-quotes at the beginning and end of the query string, and that won't work; in the working version, there are single-quotes *around* the string, but if you put quotes in variables, they're treated as *part of* the string (see ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948)). Try removing the single-quotes. If that doesn't fix it, put `set -x` before it to trace what the shell thinks is happening.

Comment: Thanks this solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically producing code that is being executed (here, a bash script producing and running a jq filter) is generally considered not only less readable (what happens in jq is very fragmented), more error-prone (this has actually brought you here), but also a principal safety risk (in a complex chain of dependencies you might not have full control over what is being executed in the end).

Therefore, you should try to modify your approach in a way that the only thing variable is the data that is being input, while the code is formulated in a way that it can react on the varying data but by itself is just a literal invariable string.

Given your sample (I presume, the code above is just a small snippet relevant to the actual question, so let this be more a hinting guide rather than a general solution), you are trying to reduce an input stream of JSON objects from `file.json` by comparing their `words` field's numeric content to a list of numbers stored in the bash array `wordDupArray`. More specifically, given a single input object, you want to pass it through to the output if `.words` holds a number that is not present in a list of numbers provided, or else drop it if the number *is* present in the list. Let's implement that.

If jq is given a stream of objects, it will process them one by one, so breaking down the input stream to a single object already happens automatically. For the comparison part, jq needs to be given the list of numbers from the bash array. As jq is a JSON processor, it'd be best to provide the list as a JSON array, thus the task at hand is to convert the bash array into a JSON array.

There are many ways to accomplish this. As the array contains only numbers, you can cash in on the fact that a number by itself is already a valid JSON document, so one approach could be to have another jq call which takes a stream of numbers and outputs them as a JSON-ecoded array using the `--slurp` (or `-s`) option, and to then, back in bash, store that output in a variable and provide it to the actual jq call using the `--argjson` option, which lets you access that JSON array as a variable inside jq.

```sh
wordDupArray=(6 1173 1 8 9 27)                   # dummy init of your bash array
jsonarray="$(jq -sc <<< "${wordDupArray[@]}")"   # will contain "[6,1173,1,8,9,27]"
jq --argjson list "$jsonarray" ' … jq filter using the array in $list … ' file.json
```

For the sake of variation, another way could be to use the `--slurpfile` option which by itself already combines a stream of JSON documents to a JSON array, and similarly lets you access that array using a variable. But as a major difference, it requires the document to be provided as a file rather than a JSON-encoded string. This can be mimicked by using [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) in bash:

```sh
wordDupArray=(6 1173 1 8 9 27)                   # dummy init of your bash array
jq --slurpfile list <(cat <<< "${wordDupArray[@]}") ' … using $list … ' file.json
```

For the main task, filtering the input objects from `file.json` according to a match in the `$list` array, you can check for inequality just as you did before but now using the array's items `$list[]` instead, and have the `all` [function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#all%2Call%28condition%29%2Call%28generator%3Bcondition%29) check whether the given condition holds for *all* items or not (all hold true means none did match).

```sh
jq --slurpfile list <(cat <<< "${wordDupArray[@]}") \
  'select([.words != $list[]] | all)' file.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/COPG8PrW02)

Again, for the sake of variation, you could also use the `IN` [function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#SQL-StyleOperators) which returns whether or not a given value appears in a given stream (not to be confused with the `in` [function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#in) which is for checking keys in objects), and the `not` [function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#and%2For%2Fnot) to `select` the cases where a match could *not* be found.

```sh
jq --slurpfile list <(cat <<< "${wordDupArray[@]}") \
  'select(.words | IN($list[]) | not)' file.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/u6lsHxqyB4)

All in all, these solutions are more stable and robust as the code is invariable and self-contained, also more comprehensible as a contiguous code is easier to follow, and even in the case of a failure you can expect more convenient error messages than the generic "compile error" which is even harder to trace if the actual code executed is unknown because of its volatility.